# Zero current switching SMPS with common emitter or source

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, common-emitter, zero-crossing

Is there any? Is it even possible that such arrangement could exist?

Im interested in SMPS where both, turn ON and turn OFF processes of all switching elements happen at zero current through that switching element. BJT or MOSFET both are ok for the solution. Preferably sunchronous rectification, also with zero current during the switching.

If that is impossible, what can be used to convince that this is truly impossible, some rule?

Comment: ZCS exists, is documented, and can be found all over the web. "Common emitter/source" is confusing, can you clarify that? Try adding a schematic and modify it to represent what you mean.

Comment: I mean that transistors are not required to have isolated supply to drive them, such as required in a totem pole configuration.

Comment: [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/zero-current-switching) has been the first result returned after searching for "zero current switching".

Comment: It is a good link, but it requires to have isolated driver for the top transistor. Im asking if it is possible to have all the transistor 'close to the ground'. So that the control signal can be stable in relation to the ground (the minus part of the battery in the example above). The top transistor in there would die if it would be driven from non-isolated signal.

Comment: You should have scrolled down the page. If isolation is excluded and if the switch is tied to the ground (common source/emitter), then the inductor would have to be in its drain/collector, and then you would be restricted to a boost converter, or a floating-output buck-boost. What topology are you looking for?

Comment: Im interested in any topology (buck, boost, buck-boost) that has these properties. That is, i will be happy if circuit will able to decrease the voltage, increase the voltage, or do any depending on control. All of those solution will be useful (so, i want to see all of them if possible). I do realise that this restriction messes up with most ZCS circuits (all that i've found). Thats why i decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SMPS that stores energy in an inductor and then releases that energy (per cycle) to an output capacitor then you must "switch" when the inductor current is non-zero because if the current in the inductor is zero then there is zero energy to transfer and the circuit does nothing. Energy stored in an inductor is: -

$$\dfrac{1}{2} LI^2$$

So, no \$I\$ means no energy transfer means no useful product.

Comment: Using LLC tank it is possible to have outside current to be 0, while current in the tank to be significant.

Comment: If you think that you get zero current switching in all switching elements then you have your answer then.